# Dart - Java buildUpon equivalent

Tags: dart, build, path, uri

Look at this simple source code written in Java:

```
Uri helpUrl = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.url_help));

        try
        {
            helpUrl = Uri.parse(mainUrl).buildUpon()
                    .appendPath("xx")
                    .appendPath("yy")
                    .appendPath("zzz.html")
                    .build();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error
        }
```

Note that `mainUrl` can be provided as http or https and also it may be `http://host/xxx` or `http://host/xxx/`. In Java, it will always work. I'm looking for a way to do the same in Dart, but it looks like there's no any `buildUpon` equivalent. Any advice how to do what I need in Dart? In dart, path has no setter, path segments list has no setter too, so it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `UriBuilder` class which is part of the `uri` package.

It's usage in your case will look something like this

```
var ub = UriBuilder.fromUri(Uri.tryParse('https://www.zombo.com/xx'));
ub.path += '/yy';
ub.path += '/zz';
Uri uri = ub.build();
// https://www.zombo.com/xx/yy/zz
```

There is no automatic management of path separators. It is just string based.

Comment: So it gives actually nothing, I can use string directly

Comment: Well I would not say UriBuilder provides nothing. It allows you to organize and manage the host, path, port, scheme, etc. all in one place, but independently. It does not however provide the specific functionality you are looking for, no. This would be a good place to use extension methods though if you are keen to have the behavior mimic java. The functionality you seek is not complicated, so I would recommend writing it as an extension method on UriBuilder, and then you can use it how you were hoping to.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But in my opinion, that's still not url parser, it's only strings parser. Cortect way to add path is like java does it, in Dart that's only string addition. Thanks for clarification, so I need to implement it by myself.